# Android parse json with text encoding is big5

Tags: android

I parsed a json data , it showed JSONException: Unterminated object at character.

I checked for a while,found the problem is the json encoding by big5 .

I have not encountered this situation.

How can i fix it ? Any help could be appreciate .

Here is my json url:
http://www.dest.org.tw/mobileapp/getnewsdata.asp

Here is my parse code:

```
private String getRouteJson(String url) throws IOException {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            StringBuilder jsonIn = new StringBuilder();
            if (responseCode == 200) {
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                    jsonIn.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, responseCode + "responseCode");
            }
            connection.disconnect();
            Log.d(TAG, jsonIn + "jsonIn");
            return jsonIn.toString();
        } 

private void showRoute(String route) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(route);
                String arrayData = jsonObject.getString("JsonData");
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(arrayData);

                for (int i = 0; i > jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    String title = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("NEWS_TITLE");

                    String content = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("NEWS_CONTENT");

                    String date = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("STARTDATE");

                    CommonNews commonNews = new CommonNews(title, content, date);
                    arrayList.add(commonNews);
                    Log.d(TAG, "title" + title);
                }

            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

then i have a advice and fix the 3rd element json , there's no JSONException now .

I can see all json data in my logcat.

But when i search title in the log , i can't see the value from String title , the problem is big5 or my json step is wrong ?
[image]

Comment: show us your json

Comment: i pasted it, thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json is not valid Json.

please check 3rd element of your *JsonData* `JsonArray`, *"NEWS_CONTENT"*

see this picture for more info [image: your error result]

Comment: thanks @Jayanth ,i fix 3rd element, there is no more JSONException now , but i can't show the data successfully, the problem is big5 or my json step is wrong ?

Comment: what exception are you getting now?

Comment: there is no exception , i upload the picture with logcat , thank you first

Comment: if your textview can't show the content or it's showing '???' that means may be your ROM doesn't have that font installed. try instaling traditional chineese font in your ROM

Comment: I have Chinese font , you misunderstanding me . I mean  i update my question with new picture , My log with the variable String title , it did not catch the value , i see my code correct...may be , so i want to confirm which one is my issue.

Comment: Do your mobile has Chinese font

Comment: yes i have  and i can see the jsonArray value in code : 

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(arrayData);

but still can't catch the String title value .

Comment: Sorry man , i found my low level error . my new mistake is  i > jsonArray.length() , it have changed to  "i <" .

Thanks @Jayanth , your first response solved my issue .

Comment: Happy if it helped you :)